# How can keep master files after merge conflict in git

Tags: git, version-control, version, git-checkout, merge-conflict-resolution

I fall in to this situation many times

```
1. I work on master branch and make some commits
2. Then i use git pull
3. Then i get auto merge fail , conflicting changes
```

Now suppose there were 5 files which were conflicting.  I want to know

```
1. How can i overwrite those conflicting files with my files on my commit
2. How can i overwrite those with chnages from master
```

after i do git pull

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use

```
git checkout --theirs -- path/to/file.txt
```

to checkout what you fetched

```
git checkout --ours -- path/to/other/file.txt
```

to checkout what you had originally.

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs git checkout --ours --
```

to use your version of all conflicted files.

Comment: how can i do for all conflicting files, rather than one by one